# How to resample OHLC dataframe in Python without peeking into the future?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance, numba

I have a Pandas DataFrame with one second frequency datetime index and columns 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close' which represent prices for a financial instrument.

I want to resample this DataFrame to 15 min (or any frequency) but without peeking into the future and still keeping the original DataFrame with one second frequency but adding four new columns for each candle. The goal is to represent how candles form in real time.

For example, for a 15 min candle, I would have four new columns in the original DataFrame named 'Open_15m', 'High_15m', 'Low_15m', 'Close_15m' which would update the values each second as a rolling OHLC.

**Keep in mind** that a 15 min candle can only start at hh:00:00 or hh:15:00 hh:30:00 or hh:45:00. This means if for example our DataFrame starts at time 09:00:00, we have rolling OHLC from 09:00:00 until 09:15:00 then we reset and start over as a new 15 min candle starts forming at 09:15:00.

I came up with the code to do this and I think its correct, but it is **too slow** for DataFrames with millions and millions of rows. If the code is correct, it would need to be sped up somehow by using Numpy & Numba for example.

```
# Function to find the nearest 15-minute floor
def nearest_quarter_hour(timestamp):
    return timestamp.floor('15T')

# Find the nearest 15-minute floor for each timestamp
df['15_min_floor'] = df.index.map(nearest_quarter_hour)

# Group by the nearest 15-minute floor and calculate rolling OHLC
rolling_df = df.groupby('15_min_floor').rolling(window='15T').agg({
    'Open': lambda x: x.iloc[0],  # First value in the window
    'High': 'max',
    'Low': 'min',
    'Close': lambda x: x.iloc[-1]  # Last value in the window
}).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

# add _15 to each column rolling df
rolling_df.columns = [f'{col}_15' for col in rolling_df.columns]

# Merge with original DataFrame
result_df = pd.concat([df, rolling_df], axis=1)
```

Comment: Instead  of agg, you can use pandas function .ohlc() and have the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) version that computes OHLC your way which is significantly faster:

```py
from numba import njit

@njit
def compute_ohlc(floor_15_min, O, H, L, C, O_out, H_out, L_out, C_out):
    first, curr_max, curr_min, last = O[0], H[0], L[0], C[0]

    last_v = floor_15_min[0]
    for i, v in enumerate(floor_15_min):
        if v != last_v:
            first, curr_max, curr_min, last = O[i], H[i], L[i], C[i]
            last_v = v
        else:
            curr_max = max(curr_max, H[i])
            curr_min = min(curr_min, L[i])
            last = C[i]

        O_out[i] = first
        H_out[i] = curr_max
        L_out[i] = curr_min
        C_out[i] = last


def compute_numba(df):
    df["15_min_floor_2"] = df.index.floor("15 min")
    df[["Open_15_2", "High_15_2", "Low_15_2", "Close_15_2"]] = np.nan

    compute_ohlc(
        df["15_min_floor_2"].values,
        df["Open"].values,
        df["High"].values,
        df["Low"].values,
        df["Close"].values,
        df["Open_15_2"].values,
        df["High_15_2"].values,
        df["Low_15_2"].values,
        df["Close_15_2"].values,
    )

compute_numba(df)
```

---

Benchmark with random `df` with 432001 rows:

```py
from timeit import timeit

import pandas as pd
from numba import njit


# generate some random data:

np.random.seed(42)

idx = pd.date_range("1-1-2023", "1-6-2023", freq="1000ms")
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Open": 50 + np.random.random(len(idx)) * 100,
        "High": 50 + np.random.random(len(idx)) * 100,
        "Low": 50 + np.random.random(len(idx)) * 100,
        "Close": 50 + np.random.random(len(idx)) * 100,
    },
    index=idx,
)


def get_result_df(df):
    def nearest_quarter_hour(timestamp):
        return timestamp.floor("15min")

    # Find the nearest 15-minute floor for each timestamp
    df["15_min_floor"] = df.index.map(nearest_quarter_hour)

    # Group by the nearest 15-minute floor and calculate rolling OHLC
    rolling_df = (
        df.groupby("15_min_floor")
        .rolling(window="15min")
        .agg(
            {
                "Open": lambda x: x.iloc[0],  # First value in the window
                "High": "max",
                "Low": "min",
                "Close": lambda x: x.iloc[-1],  # Last value in the window
            }
        )
        .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
    )

    # add _15 to each column rolling df
    rolling_df.columns = [f"{col}_15" for col in rolling_df.columns]

    # Merge with original DataFrame
    result_df = pd.concat([df, rolling_df], axis=1)

    return result_df


@njit
def compute_ohlc(floor_15_min, O, H, L, C, O_out, H_out, L_out, C_out):
    first, curr_max, curr_min, last = O[0], H[0], L[0], C[0]

    last_v = floor_15_min[0]
    for i, v in enumerate(floor_15_min):
        if v != last_v:
            first, curr_max, curr_min, last = O[i], H[i], L[i], C[i]
            last_v = v
        else:
            curr_max = max(curr_max, H[i])
            curr_min = min(curr_min, L[i])
            last = C[i]

        O_out[i] = first
        H_out[i] = curr_max
        L_out[i] = curr_min
        C_out[i] = last


def compute_numba(df):
    df["15_min_floor_2"] = df.index.floor("15 min")
    df[["Open_15_2", "High_15_2", "Low_15_2", "Close_15_2"]] = np.nan

    compute_ohlc(
        df["15_min_floor_2"].values,
        df["Open"].values,
        df["High"].values,
        df["Low"].values,
        df["Close"].values,
        df["Open_15_2"].values,
        df["High_15_2"].values,
        df["Low_15_2"].values,
        df["Close_15_2"].values,
    )


t1 = timeit("get_result_df(df)", number=1, globals=globals())
t2 = timeit("compute_numba(df)", number=1, globals=globals())

print(f"Time normal = {t1}")
print(f"Time numba =  {t2}")
```

Prints on my computer AMD 5700x (432001 rows):

```
Time normal = 29.57983471499756
Time numba =  0.2751060768496245
```

With dataframe `pd.date_range("1-1-2004", "1-1-2024", freq="1000ms")` (~631 millions of rows) the result is:

```
Time numba =  11.551695882808417
```